# How to support HTTP/2 in IIS prior to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, http, iis, windows-server-2016, http-2

HTTP/2 is/will be supported in Windows 10/Server 2016.

Is there any way to to support HTTP/2 on older versions of IIS?

PS: Can somebody help me with the following issue?

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Comment: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075)

Comment: Your link says my question might not be a good fit on this network. I disagree, but time will tell how the network feels about this question which is sure to get asked more and more as awarness about HTTP/2 grows.

Comment: "Our check takes into account tags, title and body". I've added some more appropriate tags to your question, and tweaked the spelling and grammar a little.